# replace default message in my input

Tags: angular, input

hello I need to replace in my input the message default

this is my input.component :

```
@Input () ValidationHints: any

    ngOnInit() {
    this.required = this.required !== undefined && this.required !== false
    this.disabled = this.disabled !== undefined && this.disabled !== false
    this.readonly = this.readonly !== undefined && this.readonly !== false
    this.ngModelRef = ''

    this.ValidationHints = {

      required: 'This field is required.',
      minlength: 'Field must be at least ' + this.minlength + ' characters long.',
      maxlength: 'Field cannot be more than ' + this.maxlength + ' characters long.',
      pattern: 'Please match the requested format.'

    }
  }
```

and I want when If I write my input like this :

```
 <mae-input type="text"
           minlength="3"
           maxlength="10"
           pattern="[a-z]+"
           [withCharCount]="true"
           [(ngModel)]="input"
           required
>
</mae-input>
```

i want to add something like this `ValidationHints="{required :'my new message'}"`

I know the syntax is not good but who can be have something like this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `[ValidationHints] = "{required :'my new message'}"` in your html, like this;

`<mae-input [ValidationHints] = "{required :'my new message'}"></mae-input>`

Read more about @input binding [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Comment: put a breakpoint before you assign the value to `this.ValidationHints` and you will see that the value "my new message" is there. Since you are using ngOnInit to do this change,  "my new message" will be replaced by "This field is required". first do a check to see if there are any values for `this.ValidationHints` and assign the default values if there are none.

Comment: You can simply use javascript || operator here to check if `this.ValidationHints.required` is already defined by the user. Use:
`this.ValidationHints = {required: this.ValidationHints .required || 'this field is required!'}`

Comment: where in my input component or my html file ?

Comment: because if I use this In my component file , I get something like that :

[Object,Object]

Comment: if I use `this.ValidationHints = {required: this.ValidationHints .required || 'this field is required!'}` 

i have message erreur who say required property is undefined 

and if I delete property like this :

'this.ValidationHints.required is already defined by the user. Use:
 `this.ValidationHints = {required: this.ValidationHints || 'this field is required!'}`
i dont have error but he doesn't work in have already my default message

Comment: Have this in your HTML `[ValidationHints] = "{required :'my new message'}"`. And in your component ngOnInit method, have it like this; `this.ValidationHints = {required: this.ValidationHints.required || 'this field is required!'}`

Comment: but he doesn't work I have a error message  :cannot read property 'required' of undefined 
and my message default is steel here ...

Comment: okay then add a check for this.ValidationHints as well; like this
`this.ValidationHints = {required: this.ValidationHints && this.ValidationHints.required ? this.ValidationHints.required : 'this field is required!'};`. Here i have used the ternary(conditional) operator to check if both this.ValidationHints and this.ValidationHints.required exist.

Comment: No worries, happy to help! :)